# How to bind Laravel generated url in Vue.js?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

in a component, I am getting data for a current user with Axios. I get URL for an avatar in this format: `avatars/1/mNpxJNRrRPbbWSx0kuIL40JQJIF5SM5dscTq3zpv.jpeg`

I need to insert it into Storage::disk("s3"). So how would I let the variable avatar in my component?

I tried like this: `<img :src="'Storage::disk("s3")->url(' + this.user.avatar + ')'">` But I get an error...

Comment: server side vs client side

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Not an error, it just doesn't render correctly. Renders: ")->url(' + this.user.avatar + ')'">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post 2022 answer:

It's best to use this package: https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

It allows you to use call `route()` in vue files.

---

2017 answer:

I'm not sure if you are using Storage in the blade view or the component. For clarity, one can't use the `Storage` facade in Vue components. It's only for Laravel.

You have two options: allow the component to accept a prop or create a Laravel route that returns the URL with the help of `Storage` facade.

#Option 1 - Prop passing

In your blade view,

```
<my-component :src="'{{ Storage::disk("s3")->url(' + this.user.avatar + ')' }}">
```

#Option 2 - Laravel route

Create a simple route, something like

```
Route::get('api/my-avatar', UserController@getAvatar')
```

In your the UserController

```
public function getAvatar()
{
    return Storage::disk("s3")->url( auth()->user()->avatar );
}
```

and call that route from axios.

Comment: In your second option can you show an example of how the image will be rendered in an `<img .../>` tag in vue. Will the *src* attribute of the image points to the laravel route directly?

Comment: @ultrasamad Yes, the `src` attribute will directly point to `https://example.test/api/my-avatar`.